# Project Addin to Create VB Projects VS 2005 IDE

Tags: vb.net

My VS 2005 currently allows to create only Projects in C#. Is there any seperate Add In available for download using whcih I can Create VB.Net Projects.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because you chose to install only C# during the Visual Studio installation, just insert your Visual Studio CD and make sure VB is selected in the custom install.

If you have the Express edition, it seems to support only one language, Maybe you can install two different versions side-by-side. Here is the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/).